# Деление многочлена без класов и векторов

Tags: c++

```
void division(int* arr1, int n, int* arr2, int m, int* result, int& nm) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= (n - m); j++)
    {
        result[j] = arr1[n - j] / arr2[m];
 
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i >= (n - (m + j)))
                arr1[i] = (arr1[i] - (arr2[i + j - (n - m)] * result[j]));
        }
    }
}
```

Здраствуйте,вот чет пробовал, но не получилось, не могли бы поправить, а то уже час не могу никак, буду благодарен.Входние дание(x^3-12x^2-42 and x-3 и должно x^2-9x-27 и остато 127.Но тут почемуто не то в коде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int k = (n - m); k >= 0;  k--)
{
    result[k] = arr1[k + m] / arr2[m];
    for (int j = k + m - 1; j >=k; j--)
            arr1[j] -= arr2[j-k] * result[k];
}
```

result `-27, -9, 1, 0`
остаток в arr1 `-123` (нужно брать соотв. n и m количество членов)
[ideone](https://ideone.com/IMk122)